# Proof for Convergence of Quotient of Sums

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, number-theory, real-numbers

I have a question regarding the divergence or convergence of the quotient of two a divergent sum and a sum which I dont know if it does converge or diverge. The quotient of the two sums looks like this:

$$
\lim_{k \to \infty}\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{k}\biggl(\sum_{m=0}^{a^{2n}-a^{2n-1}-1}{\frac{1}{a^{2n-1}+m}}-\sum_{m=0}^{a^{2n-1}-a^{2n-2}-1}{\frac{1}{a^{2n-2}+m}}\biggr)}{\sum_{n=1}^{k}n^{-1}}
$$

where you can assume that $a$ is an integer greater or equal to $2$. Now I would like to show that this quotient approaches zero as $k$ goes to $\infty$. So far I was able to show (which is quiet easy) that:

$$
\sum_{m=0}^{a^{2n}-a^{2n-1}-1}{\frac{1}{a^{2n-1}+m}}\leq\frac{a^{2n}-a^{2n-1}-1}{2}\biggl(\frac{1}{a^{2n-1}}-\frac{1}{a^{2n}-1}\biggr)
$$

No for further simplicity of the formulas I will define $a^{2n}-a^{2n-1}-1 = \{b_n\}$ and $a^{2n-1}-a^{2n-2}-1 = \{c_n\} = \{b_{n-1}\}$. Then I was able to show that

$$
\lim_{k \to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^{k}\biggl[\frac{b_n}{2}\biggl(\frac{1}{a^{2n-1}}-\frac{1}{a^{2n}-1}\biggr)-\frac{b_{n-1}}{2}\biggl(\frac{1}{a^{2n-2}}-\frac{1}{a^{2n-1}-1}\biggr)\biggr]
$$

converges which implies that my quotient for this new difference of sums does converge. Sadly I was not able to show that:

$$
\frac{b_n}{2}\biggl(\frac{1}{a^{2n-1}}-\frac{1}{a^{2n}-1}\biggr)-\frac{b_{n-1}}{2}\biggl(\frac{1}{a^{2n-2}}-\frac{1}{a^{2n-1}-1}\biggr) \geq \sum_{m=0}^{b_n}{\frac{1}{a^{2n-1}+m}}-\sum_{m=0}^{b_{n-1}}{\frac{1}{a^{2n-2}+m}}
$$

So I do think to show that this inequality holds would be a relatively easy way to show that my quotient of sums does converge to zero. I am very happy if someone is able to give me some ideas or other possible approaches or even a complete sketch of a proof. I may note for the reader that I was able to show that:

$$
\sum_{m=0}^{b_n}{\frac{1}{a^{2n-1}+m}}\geq {b_{n}}\biggl(\frac{1}{a^{2n-1}+\frac{1}{2}b_n}\biggr)
$$

as well as that:

$$
\lim_{k \to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^{k}\biggl[\frac{b_n}{2}\biggl(\frac{1}{a^{2n-1}}-\frac{1}{a^{2n}-1}\biggr)-{b_{n-1}}\biggl(\frac{1}{a^{2n-2}+\frac{1}{2}b_{n-1}}\biggr)\biggr]
$$

does not converge. When looking at the differences between the LHS and the RHS of the two inequalities I showed I also wasnt able to find something which is bigger than the summands of my original difference of series and does converge. So any help is really, really appreciated!